# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar títulos con array dentro de un loop?

Tags: php, html, array, while, bucles

Quiero duplicar un trozo de html y dentro de ese mismo meter más imágenes y cosas. Eso me funciona sin problema. Lo único es que en cada loop quiero que se vaya cambiando el título de ese trozo de html, es decir, primero sería:

```
echo($titles[0]) y luego echo($titles[1])
```

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<?php
$titles = array("title1", "title2");
$i=1;
while ($i<=2){
?>

<h1><?php echo($titles[0]) ?></h1>

<?php 
$i=$i+1;            
 } // FINAL WHILE
?>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres. Y dado que dices que tienes más cosas, puedes organizar un solo array que sea asociativo con el contenido que quieras, si está a tu alcance organizar los datos de otra forma claro está... Me refiero a un array así: `$allData=array ( array( 'title'=>'Titulo 1', array('Dato1','Dato2') ), array( 'title'=>'Titulo 2', array('Dato3','Dato4') ) );` luego sería cuestión de leerlo buscando la clave `title` y dentro los valores de `Dato1, DatoN` en el sub-array. Si no te interesa así, de todos modos conviene que expliques mejor lo que quieres pues no se entiende.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que siempre accedes a la misma posición del arreglo. Deberia quedar de esta forma:

```
<?php
$titles = array("title1", "title2");
$i=1;
while ($i<=2){
?>

<h1><?php echo($titles[$i-1]) ?></h1>

<?php 
$i=$i+1;            
} // FINAL WHILE
?>
```